# What is a good world reference atlas with information for each country?

Tags: data, references

[I'm not sure if this is the right StackExchange site for this question, but it was the closest I could find to general geography.]

I love learning about the countries of the world, and my favorite book has been "World Reference Atlas: A-Z factfile and detailed mapping of all the world's nations," published by DK. It has 2-4 pages on each country in the world, with their map, history, and info about economy, population, etc. However, my version is the 1998 edition, and they haven't revised it since (I think). Is there a comparable book out there?

Comment: This question has no clear GIS component.

Comment: @Vince I'd argue that it has a clear *geographic* component and isn't that different to questions about data sources that are at the fringe of GIS.SE and opendata.SE.

Comment: National Geographic 10th Edition (2015) http://shop.nationalgeographic.com/ngs/product/books/atlases-and-almanacs/national-geographic-atlas-of-the-world--10th-edition---hardcover?npd&npd& (disclaimer: have worked on this in the past)

Comment: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/q/3894/115

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot advise a specific book but there are a ton of great online ressources for the scope you outlined. Some popular examples:

- [CIA World Factbook](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/) - probably the closest to the book you mentioned
- [FAO stat](http://faostat.fao.org/) - for browsing and comparing statistical data of different countries
- [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) - for quick graphs and comparisons of countries, e.g. [GDP USA vs China](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gdp+usa+vs+china&lk=4&num=1)
- [TheTrueSize](http://thetruesize.com/) - to compare the true size of countries relative to each other

---

**edit:**

Actually I can advise a specific book. The CIA World Factbook is available in print format as well. ISBN: 978-1634503280 for the 2016 edition.